# HTTP Module for Javascript application IIS

Tags: angular, iis, httpmodule

IIS HTTP Module can be configured only for the ASP.Net / MVC application in IIS? Because I have Angular 2 application (which is Html and js only) and deployed it in IIS, it works well but I need to read the request header while accessing the Angular application URL.

So, I am thinking of to create a HTTP Module as mentioned like this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-iis-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework)

And in my Angular application web.config file, created a module element as below.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
        <modules>
            <add name="MyModule" type="SiteMinderTokenReader.MyModule" />
        </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But the module not works as expected

This my module code.

```
namespace SiteMinderTokenHandler
{
    public class MyModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
            context.EndRequest += new EventHandler(context_EndRequest);
        }

        void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            HttpApplication httpApplication = (HttpApplication)sender;
            httpApplication.Context.Response.Write("<h1>The header....</h1>");
        }

        void context_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication httpApplication = (HttpApplication)sender;
            httpApplication.Context.Response.Write("<h6>The footer....</h6>");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that your module does not run??

Comment: @UmarKarimabadi: Yes, It's not running.

Answer (score 0):

Your module does not run because you are serving static content. In order to make your module run for all content, you need to add this attribute.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
   <add name="MyModule" type="SiteMinderTokenReader.MyModule"/>
</modules>
```

> runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"

This will run your module for all requests, even static content. Also, make sure your "type" is correct. The full namespace included.

Comment: I included my module code here and this is how I changed my web.config file.  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <add name="Handler" type="SiteMinderTokenHandler.Handler" />
        </modules>